# How to create a Listener for api call which gives live data in flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, listener

I have a app, there is one screen where the data I am showing from api, keeps changing in seconds.
So to show user the latest data on screen I am calling that api using `Timer.periodic` in duration  3 seconds. now the api calls everytime after 3 seconds brings the latest data and I show that in my app.

But I think this is not a best practice, and I dont want to keep it this way, I want to create something like `listener` which does work under the hood and gives me latest data from the server.

I don't know how to do this. I can't find any good article/tutorial.
Can someone please help !!.

Comment: You need to do this on your backend side. You can create `webSocket` on your backend with the webSocket URL you can listen for changes in flutter

Comment: Can you share a resoure/article that explains in a good way. @RohanJariwala

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you should use a socket so instead of fetching the info from the app to the server you should send the info from the server to the app anytime the server has a new version of the data.

You could use socket.io to create your socket server and later you can create the listeners on your app.

Comment: Can you share a resoure/article that explains in a good way. @CarlosSandoval

Comment: https://somniosoftware.com/post/real-time-apps-with-flutter-and-websockets

Comment: Is it neccessary to user stream or bloc, Can we do it using GetX and node. @CarlosSandoval

Comment: yes, you can use getx